# Transition on labels in d3 pie/donut chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm making a donut chart that can be switched between several different data sets. I have been able to get the slices to transition nicely, and am positioning the labels with arc.centroid, but I can't figure out how to apply the arc tweening function to the labels. I think I've almost got it, any hints would be appreciated.

Here's a live example: http://jsbin.com/otAjUSO/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add same transition effect to label group also

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/f46Ys/)**

```
 label_group.data(pie)
  .transition().duration(750)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    var c = arc.centroid(d);
  return "translate(" + c[0] +"," + c[1] + ")";
    })
```

Comment: Oh, wow, it was just the ordering of the `.transition()` and `.attr()` methods. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a transition to the group:

```
label_group.data(pie)
  .transition().duration(750)
  // The above transition is all you need
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    var c = arc.centroid(d);
    return "translate(" + c[0] +"," + c[1] + ")";
  });
```

Comment: I've accepted Manoj's answer because he included a demo, but thanks!